# How to change background view color in android?

Tags: android, background, android-alertdialog

How to change background view color when alert dialog button is clicked  and dialog box is popuped in android. Such as when dialog box is popuped background view color becomes dark.

Comment: where is your  code?

Comment: i do not need to change alert dialog background color. My requirement is to change the color of background view when alert dialog button is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
v.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

or

```
v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parse("#ffffff"));
```

this will change the background color to `white`

Answer (score 0):

Add XML on the top layer,
Image View preferred as you can give it any color you want

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_OverlayImage"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:clickable="true"   />
```

Initially set its visibility to GONE

And on click, when your dialog box opens set it to visible

```
overlayImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Set it back to gone on any button pressed in dialog

```
overlayImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: @zafarimam well keep that background view in a variable (v in my case)....